# Security issue ? User with restricted scope can access ALL orders on a multiwebsite setup

Tags: orders, rest-api, security, scope, magento2-cloud

Using Magento Cloud EE here but this issue might be the same on CE I'm not sure.

- Create user `foo`
- Create role test
- Assign `foo` to `test`
- Restrict website scope for `test` to `www.website1.com` only
- Login with account `foo` : You can only browse orders made on `www.website1.com` : **Good!**
- Connect using Rest API with same credentials : You can browse ALL orders, from ALL websites.
- **WoW** !

Am I missing something here ?

Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: can you tell us which endpoint(s) did you call?

Answer (score 0):

Uhmm ok, I just checked **on a 2.4.1 Commerce edition and the problem you mentioned replicates exactly as described above**, for example, on the https://magento.redoc.ly/2.3.7-admin/tag/ordersid#operation/salesOrderRepositoryV1GetGet endpoint.

By checking both the `webapi.xml` and `acl.xml` in the vendor/magento/module-sales/ folder, there is no indication that the role website scope is taken into account.

Also, the documentation presented in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/create-access-control-list-rule.html#step-3-restrict-web-api-access doesn't state anything regarding role scope on Magento Commerce.

---

***LE*** also, if by *'CE'* you mean community/ open source edition, then this is not a problem there since role website scope is introduced as a feature only in Commerce edition (therefore Cloud edition too).

Comment: All right so ... That's not a security issue, it's a feature right ? :'(
Am I the only one to be "surprised" how unsafe it is ?

Comment: actually no, I would have expected the same behavior as in admin, tbh. Looks like a partial feature if I may say so. As for whether this is a security issue or not, it depends on the case, but it can perceived as such.

Comment: Yes I would have expected the same behaviour, meaning that scope filtering should occur too. In a multiple websites setup, where you provide a service to your customers who are commercial competitors, you definitely DON'T want them to see each other's orders .....

Comment: yes, ofc, i understand. this could be treated as both a business related issue as well as a security issue, namely disclosure of sensitive data, both with a big impact.